# Restcomm outbound call to DID registered at Nexmo

Tags: ivr, vonage, restcomm

What is the proper way to initiate an outbound call from the Restcomm server to a DID/PSTN phone?

- I have a Nexmo number provisioned
- Inbound calls work

I have tried this curl command to initiate an outbound call

```
curl -X POST http://[account sid]:[auth token]@[restcomm server ip]:8080/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/[account sid]/Calls.json -d "From=sip:[number provisioned at Nexmo, e.g. 12125551234]@sip.nexmo.com" -d "To=sip:[my number, e.g. 12125551234]@sip.nexmo.com" -d "Url=[source of xml]"
```

The result is this log entry:

```
Call SID [call sid removed]
From [The Nexmo number--removed]
Date Thu, 17 Sep 2015 16:30:07 -0400
To [My number--removed]
Start Time Sep 17, 2015 4:30:07 PM
Direction outbound-api
End Time Status QUEUED
Duration seconds
Price $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mattias,

In order to use restcomm for outbound calls with Nexmo, you need to update the
restcomm.conf file

Go to $RESTCOMM_HOME/bin/restcomm/restcomm.conf

Edit the Outbound proxy as shown below. Restart Restcomm. This will tell restcomm to forward all outbound SIP calls through Nexmo.

```
# Address for outbound calls
OUTBOUND_PROXY='sip.nexmo.com' #Provide port if different than 5060
OUTBOUND_PROXY_USERNAME='NEXMO_KEY'
OUTBOUND_PROXY_PASSWORD='NEXMO_SECRET'
```

Are you familiar with creating an RVD Voice App?

I will suggest that you use a SIP phone to make a call to the Destination DID so that you can hear audio.

Regards

Charles